# Letter Opener Gem in Rails 4 doesn't open link in preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm using the [Letter Opener gem](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) to preview emails but if I click on a link that routes to an url in my application - nothing happens.

If I copy the link url from the preview and paste it into the address bar the link works...

Any idea?

**config/development.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
```

**views/app_mailer/send_mail.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Home Page", root_url %>
```

**The actual HTML**

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home</a>
```

Comment: If what you described is accurate the only scenario I can come up with is some JS might be blocking the link click.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the browser is trying to open the link inside a frame in the same window as your preview window. If you look at your browser's developer tools console, you will probably see an error like this when you click any `localhost` link:

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:3000/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

The solution is to make the link open in a new window or tab, by adding the `target` attribute, like this:

```
<%= link_to "Home Page", root_url, target: '_blank' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

[@monfresh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29544812) is correct, however here's another solution..

[Rails 4 sets the default for `X-Frame-Options` to `SAMEORIGIN`](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/new-in-rails-4#default-headers) which would fix your issue and still prevent other potentially malicious websites from hosting your site in iframes.

If you're happy with this slightly more relaxed setting just remove any overrides for `X-Frame-Options` you might have added to `/config/application.rb` or the `/config/environment/*.rb` files

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem but i was not getting any error though.
To get the error/exception, I used the `bang` operator to throw the error and tried shooting the email from the console, as show below and got the exact issue as why the emails where not showing up on the browser.

```
##console output
2.6.6 :001 > UserMailer.test_email(User.last.id).deliver!
  // removing other logs for more clarity
  Rendering user_mailer/test_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered user_mailer/test_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (Duration: 26.7ms | Allocations: 7426)
UserMailer#test_email: processed outbound mail in 42.1ms
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/myusername/workspace/appname/tmp/letter_opener/1616711245_6137273_df0084b)
```

I fixed the permission issue with  - `sudo chmod -R 0777 tmp/`

problem fixed and started getting emails opening up in the browser rather than silently failing without any error.